# Express API returns NOTHING in Post Request

Tags: javascript, rest, api, express, postman

Im trying to make a jwt auth api in express, everything worked fine until, today when give the post request with postman returns only {}

here is the code for server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const app = express();
const auth = require("./rutas/auth");
dotenv.config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
mongoose.connect(process.env.URI, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/auth", auth);
// app.use("/api/crud", crud);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Conectado en el puerto ${port}`);
});
```

here is the code for auth.js where post request gives me {}

```js
const express = require("express");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../modelos/User");
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const usuarios = await User.find();
  res.send(usuarios);
});
router.post("/sign", async (req, res) => {
  const { nombre, email, contraseña } = req.body;
  res.json(req.body);
  console.log(req.body);
});
router.post("/login", [], async (req, res) => {
  const { email, contraseña } = req.body;
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  try {
    //Encontrar usuario en BD
    const usuario = await User.findOne({ email });
    const isValido = await bcrypt.compare(contraseña, usuario.contraseña);
    if (isValido) {
      const payload = {
        id: usuario._id
      };
      const token = jwt.sign(payload, "secretomagico", { expiresIn: "1h" });
      req.header("auth-token", token);
      res.send("En BD");
    }
  } catch (error) {}
});
module.exports = router;
```

here is the json message i send in postman:
{
"nombre":"Jack",
"contraseña":12345678,
"email":"biggpoppa@gmail.com"
}

Comment: You didnt say which post route is returning {}. You have two post routes, /sign and /login

Comment: it was the post route

Comment: You have two post routes, one under "/sign" and one under "/login"; when your using postman are you putting in "http://localhost:port/login" or "http://localhost:port/sign"

Comment: yes i use the route sign, already find the problem it was with the content-type of postman, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, to anyone with the same problem, in postman you got to put in the header Content-Type: application/json. 
i had Contetn-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded plus the one said before